# Utilizar DataSet en C#

Tags: c#, dataset

soy nueva usando en C#.  Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de C# con SQL, tengo un procedimiento almacenado que trae el listado de los insumos y se debe mostrar en el gridview de acuerdo a los parámetros de búsqueda, pero al intentar usar el DataSet no me lo reconoce. El DataSet esta ubicado dentro de la carpeta "App_Code".  El nombre del DataSet es "DS_INGRESO_PAC", el namespace que tiene es "ModuloPAC.App_Code".
Incluso intente crear una clase pero igual no lo reconoce. El codigo de mi clase es:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;

namespace ModuloPAC.App_Code.DAL
{
    public class Insumos
    {
        public DataTable ListadoInsumos(string descripcionInsumo)
        {
            DataTable resultado = null;

            return resultado;

        }

    }
}
```

Como pruebas intente colocarlo en la raíz y allí si lo reconoce.  Alguien me puede ayudar, o si saben si este problema es algo sobre permisos a las carpetas.

Comment: HOla! Bienvenidx a SOes. Código como texto, por favor :) Puedes [edit] la pregunta todo lo que quieras para irla mejorando, responder a los comentarios con preguntas  y facilitar las respuestas

Answer (score 0):

creo recordar que el código en la carpeta app_code no se compila al generar los dll de la aplicación, por lo que no lo puedes referenciar desde otra clase fuera de esa carpeta, al mover el .cs al raíz esa clase puede ser compilada y usada desde cualquier parte del proyecto (siempre y cuando sea 'public')